# flash cannot find xml file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

i have a flash app that loads data from an xml file.

i get a network error 404 not found for the xml file but it shows the correct path to the xml file.

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.mysite.com/movie/StartDATA.xml"  this path is correct.

also i can call up this XML file in browser.

also this works on my localhost, just will not work on live server (have tried 2 different servers).

i thought a permission problem so i set XML to read/write all but also that does not work.

i am out of ideas now.

Comment: Is the SWF and HTML being hosted on the same server as the XML file?

Comment: yes...also all files in same dir/ i think this is permissions prob because the app connects with 2 xml files and only one it cannot connect/find